# Issue with sending codeigniter view in email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send email in codeigniter. I'm sending view in message body.But I'm getting error as shown below:

[image: Error]

It displaying view below the error. 
My code is as below.

```
$msg = $this->load->view('FolderName/sendEmail.php',TRUE);
```

I have also tried

```
$msg = $this->load->view('FolderName/sendEmail.php',"",TRUE);
```

But with this code I'm not receiving any email. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Remove .php from file name and try again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two changes:

If the view file has a php extension, you should remove the `.php` from the first parameter (just use `$this->load->view('FolderName/sendEmail');`).

Also, you need to pass an empty second parameter if you're not passing data from the controller to the view, as the `TRUE` parameter you are using in order to get the HTML back in the controller is the third parameter, not the second.

try `$this->load->view('FolderName/sendEmail, NULL, TRUE');`

Comment: same error message? what exactly is on the line reported by the error message?

Comment: The actual problem is with image, if the view page has image, emails are not sending. Otherwise it is working with html code.